# Modelling e-commerce website checkout

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic, e-commerce

Typically, when a customer clicks the "checkout" button on an e-commerce website, they go through a checkout process something like this:

1. Update/confirm product quantities in shopping cart
2. Enter address, choose shipping method
3. Enter credit card details
4. Review all order details, click "confirm" to make payment
5. "Thank you" page with order number

After the customer clicks "Confirm" on step 4 of the checkout, we would typically want to create some database objects including:

- `Order`
- `Invoice` (which has a relation to the corresponding `Order`)
- `Payment` (which has a relation to the corresponding `Invoice`)

My first thought was that something like this should occur:

1. Create an `Order` object with the order details
2. Create an `Invoice` object with the total cost of the order
3. Create a `Payment` object with `status=PENDING` and attempt to charge the credit card
4. If charge succeeds, update the `Payment` to `status=SUCCESS` and redirect customer to "thank you" page
5. If charge fails, update the `Payment` to `status=FAIL` and return customer to step 4 with error message displayed

However, there is a problem with this flow: If the charge fails and the customer is returned to step 4, a duplicate `Order` and `Invoice` will be  generated if they click "Confirm" again to re-attempt payment.

To avoid this, we could modify this flow to only create a new `Order` and `Invoice` if they do not already exist. However, the problem with that is that the user may click back to step 1, change the order, and then try to pay again. In this case, the `Order` and `Invoice` objects will be incorrect because the order has been changed.

So to avoid this, we could instead update the existing `Order` and `Invoice` if they already exist, but this now seems overly complicated, and also breaks a common convention that invoices should be immutable.

What is the best way to model this?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - nothing happens until after the transaction has been confirmed. If the credit card does not go through you try again by showing them the billing form again with the relevant error messages. It could have been a simple error. Or it could be they aren't really going to do the order.

An 'invoice' implies that money is owed. And actually that could be an interesting way to describe the in process order as the customer is shopping. But you are at the last step, and once the transaction has gone through its just an Order. So you don't need to create anything separate.

========= edit

Hey i really appreciate you detailing out the invoice requirements in your other comment - did not know that. And i still will push back on this idea of having to create an order before you know that there will be an order at all.

Otherwise - why don't you do the same thing on your Invoice as you are doing with payment? It seems like the invoice is only 'immutable' after the transaction is complete. So have a status field - pending, success, fail, etc. and very important if the payment fails - before submitting the transaction - you are checking the cart etc to reconfirm all the totals.

And you need to make it impossible for the customer to click back and change an order. There has to be a token or some kind of identifier with the cart that makes this impossible.

Also i would highly recommend - that if an order is changed - such as a return, exchange, etc - that you issue a new order. Because part of that change is also accounting for the change in inventory on hand.

Comment: I considered that but then I will have failed `Payment` objects that are not linked to any order or customer.

Comment: Thanks, I think what I will do is only create the `Order` and `Invoice` objects once payment succeeds, and to have a `Payment.notes` field where I can add a message about what the payment was for for failed payments.